# Remove all files whose names match a particular pattern

Tags: shell, wildcards

These are files in my home directory:

```
23233.txt
3233.txt
ba233.txt
kh23.txt
khalith
main.sh
s2233.txt
tr233.txt
WWW.txt
```

How may I remove all files whose names start with two lower-case letters, followed by two digits and the extension `.txt`, e.g. `kh23.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
find /path/to/parent/dir/ -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2}\.txt' -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 4):

The pattern you may be looking for is

```
[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9].txt
```

This will match any name in the current directory consisting of exactly two lowercase characters, followed by two digits, followed by the literal string `.txt`.

Filename globbing patterns are, unlike regular expressions, automatically anchored to the start and end of the string, so we don't have to say anything special about the filenames not having characters before the first of the two lowercase character or after the `.txt`.

You may either use this pattern with `rm` directly:

```
$ rm "$HOME"/[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9].txt
```

or, if you want to recurse down into all subdirectories, with `find`:

```
$ find "$HOME" -name "[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9].txt" -delete
```

If your implementation of `find` does not support `-delete`, consider the following instead:

```
$ find "$HOME" -name "[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9].txt" -exec rm {} +
```

---

PS: Use the word *digit* when you mean a number between zero and nine. A *number* is a bit vague, especially since 233, which is part of several of the example filenames, is a number. <sub>(I have since edited the question to remove this ambiguity)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your response. find  -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2}\.txt' this works for me :)

Comment: Even this command works fine.. find  -name "[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9].txt" -exec rm {} \;

Comment: @KhalithBasha Good. Notice that you will have to either _be in_ your home directory, or give `find` the home directory to search, to be able to find the files in your home directory.